# Pandas Create mask conditioned on 3 columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a Dataframe of 3M rows. I would like to create a mask which returns the indices of rows and values where 3 columns are of equal value.

I thought this should work:

```
mask =  df.loc[ df['column_1'] == df['column_2'] & df['column_2'] == df['column_3'] & df['column_1'] == df['column_3'] ]
```

However I get `the truth value of a series is ambiguous`

I tried this but get the same error:

`mask =  df.loc[ np.any(df['column_1'] == df['column_2'] & df['column_2'] == df['column_3'] & df['column_1'] == df['column_3']) ]`

`mask =  df.loc[ np.where(df['column_1'] == df['column_2'] & df['column_2'] == df['column_3'] & df['column_1'] == df['column_3']) ]`

I appreciate the help with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the dataframe:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame()
     .assign(a=['hej', 'ful'],
             b=['hej', 'ful'],
             c=['hej', 'ful']))
```

You can use:

```
(df
 .assign(same=lambda x: (x.a == x.b) & (x.b == x.c))
 .loc[lambda x: x.same == True]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

place the conditions within parenthesis to ensure precedence of operations i.e., column1 and colums2 are compared for equality instead of column 2 "and" column2

```
mask =  df.loc[ 
    (df['column_1'] == df['column_2']) & 
    (df['column_2'] == df['column_3']) & 
    (df['column_1'] == df['column_3']) ]
```

Comment: thanks, now i get the error `boolean array expected for the condition not object`

Comment: if you post a MRE, i'll be able to validate. My response was for the earlier issue you were facing and provided the corrected solution for that part  .  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I see what you mean but the real ask is what I could do to make it actually work; your solution does not solve the issue. But I upvoted your answer. thanks

Comment: *'the truth value of a series is ambiguous'* was the issue in your question. if you post data as code with the expectation, soeone can try to solve it

Comment: when you print (mask), does it not give you the rows that meet the criteria?

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
df.loc[df.apply(lambda x: (x == x.min()).all(), axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3
1     5     5     5
3     3     3     3
```

Data:

```
from io import StringIO

text = """
col1    col2    col3
1   3   2
5   5   5
2   5   1
3   3   3
3   2   5
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), sep='\s+')
df = df.astype(str)
```

Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

text = """
col1    col2    col3
1   3   2
5   5   5
2   5   1
3   3   3
3   2   5
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), sep='\s+')
df = df.astype(str)

df.loc[df.apply(lambda x: (x == x.min()).all(), axis=1)]
```

Comment: thanks! if I wanted to convert the df values to `string` before doing the comparison, can I use `.astype(str)` ? could you show an example?

Comment: Yes, @uniXVanXcel. I have just added `df = df.astype(str)` to the data creation and it works fine: please, see my updated solution.

Comment: ah, i get `str has no attribute all`

Comment: Just run the complete code I have just added to my solution: it should work fine, @uniXVanXcel!

Comment: :) ok thnks will do

Comment: you know the other answer ended up working..I wish I could choose 2 answers :) because you helped me a lot as well, but I had issues with the string conversion of my dataframe; thanks again!

Comment: That is fine that you have accepted another solution, @uniXVanXcel! I am happy for having helped you!

Comment: I have another question, do you think you could give me help with that one?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73875162/python-panda-modify-dataframe-with-mask-and-create-new-dataframe    ; will def select it as the answer if you are able to solve it :)